# Brillouin’s Diversity Index

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to calculate the Brillouin’s Diversity Index in groups in Python according to column "a" using pandas and numpy. But something wrong happened.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def Brillouin_Index(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x["Brillouin_Index"] = (np.log10(np.math.factorial(np.sum(x))) - np.sum(np.log10(np.math.factorial(x[i])))) / np.sum(x)
        return x
a = list("ABCDEADECS")
b = [12,23,12,12,32,34,21,2,10,5]
c = {"a":a,"b":b}
data = pd.DataFrame(c)
data
data.groupby("a").apply(Brillouin_Index)
```

I executed the above code and there are two errors.

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log10'
```

The specific formula see the following link [Brillouin’s Diversity Index](http://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/diversity-indices/brillouins-diversity-index/)

I used other software to calculate the values of each group

1. H_A = 0.2965
2. H_B = 0
3. H_C = 0.264
4. H_D = 0.259
5. H_E = 0.08085
6. H_S = 0

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I use R to calculate the Brillouin’s Diversity Index in groups.The code is below:

```
Brillouin_Diversity_Index <- function(x)
{  N <- sum(x)

 (log10(factorial(N)) - sum(log10(factorial(x)))) / N

}

dt <- data.table(x = c("A","B","C","D","E","A","D","E","C","S"),
y = c(12,23,12,12,32,34,21,2,10,5))
dt[,Brillouin_Diversity_Index(y),by = .(x)]
```

1. x         V1
2. A 0.23021887
3. B 0.00000000
4. C 0.26412121
5. D 0.25909105
6. E 0.08085185
7. S 0.00000000